# After upgrading to Grails 3.2.10 and GORM 6.1.4, async namespace is missing on Domain Objects

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Classes in grails-app/domain no longer seem to be able to resolve .async

So, previously I could do

```
Contact.async.task {
}
```

But now i'm getting a "No such property: async for class"

Has anyone else seen this??

I have the following in the build.gradle for the plugin and the parent project:

compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-async:$gormVersion"

Answer (score 1):

Finally stumbled onto this post that explains async issue.. would be sweet to have this referenced in the "What's New" when you choose to use Grails versions that move from GORM 6.0 to 6.1

https://github.com/grails/gorm-hibernate5/blob/master/docs/src/docs/asciidoc/introduction/upgradeNotes.adoc

Relevant part:

> In order to enable GORM Async you need to add the necessary dependency to build.gradle:

```
compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-async:{version}"
```

> And make your entities implement the AsyncEntity trait:

```
import grails.gorm.async.*

class Person implements AsyncEntity<Person> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, even after manually inserting AsyncEntity in my domain objects, ran into this error and postponed the GORM upgrade for now... symbol:   : error: cannot find symbol
@org.codehaus.groovy.transform.trait.Traits.Implemented() public  D refresh() { return null;}